# How to cache all product images(around 1000) from firebase storage using angular 4 application?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

How to cache all my website product images(around 1000) from firebase storage using angular 4 application. Images are loading on homepage very slowly.

Is there way that can cache all images on application startup or load on the first time cache them and use from there?

I tried searching online but didn't much information with angular 4/5. can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 5):

There are several possibilities. Here are some suggestions:

- When you upload a file to Firebase Storage, you can provide metadata properties such as the `cacheControl`. This property will be used to cache the file based on your specification. An example is presented in [Firebase documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#update_file_metadata)
- If you are using Firebase Hosting, you can configure your `firebase.json` to cache static assets, like images, in the CDN level with `Cache-Control` header. An example of this feature is presented in [documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-headers)
- Also, you can use a service worker, maybe with [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/#get-started), with a `cacheFirst` strategy to cache all products images into the user browser. Then, after first cache, the images will be load from local cache first.
- In Angular scenario, you also can use a Lazy Load approach to progressive load the images from server. Basically, you need to use a placeholder in `src` attribute (like Medium blur effect) and async load the images from server. Then, Angular can displays the images reactively using an Observer, for example. An agnostic framework library deals with this issue is [Blazy](https://github.com/dinbror/blazy/).

With these approaches your app will load the images faster.